# setting the filename for a downloaded file in a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, download

I have a controller action that allows a user to download a file with an extension of .ppt . It's not really a powerpoint binary, just an xml-ish format that powerpoint can read. the file is downloaded from the show action of a controller called ElementsController, but the show action is not actually defined in the controller, there is, however, a template file for it in app/views/elements/show.ppt.builder .  I have the Mime::Type registered in config/initializers/mime_types.rb as such:

`Mime::Type.register "multipart/related", :ppt`

and the file downloads properly, and opens with powerpoint on a windows system, yet the problem is the filename.  the name of the file is 3.ppt where three is the id parameter in the url.  I would like to know if there is a way to set the filename to something a little more descriptive than 3.ppt.

thx,

-C

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could use [send_data](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_data):

```
send_data pptdata, :filename => 'your_file_name.ppt', 
   :disposition => 'inline', :type => "multipart/related"
```

Another advantage of this is you can use x-sendfile, so that you're mongrel/thin isn't waiting while the client downloads the data.

---

Another option would be to have a route like:

/elements/3/files/foo.ppt

Then in your show method for the FilesController you can send whatever the id parameter would be.

Comment: the problem with send_data is that i would have to open up the method in the controller and define respond_to do |format|, which is what i'm trying to avoid.

Comment: it just seems like there should be no reason to actually set respond_to in your individual controller actions, because rails does it automatically for you if you follow naming conventions and register your mime-types. I only want to set the filename, rather than redefine the whole action.

Comment: I guess the thing is you're requesting a URI with a format.  I would expect it to return a document with that name.  Did you see my other suggestion?

Answer (score 15):

A possible example:

```
def show
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # show.html.erb
        format.ppt {
            response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=\"#{@item.filename}.ppt\""
        } # show.ppt.erb
        format.xml  { render :xml => @item }
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me answer [my own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902052/rails-3-set-the-filename-in-a-respond-to/12902958).

Answer (score 5):

Ok. This is an answer for a very old question, but as of Rails 3.2 the most simple way is to set it like:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @product }
  format.csv { send_data @product.to_csv, :filename => "New-Product-filename.csv" }
  format.xls 
end
```

[Source API Doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_data)