# Rails 3 - set the filename in a respond_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This seems like it should be simple, but I can't seem to find a straight answer.

I have added a csv mime-type, and the following seems to work, **except** that the downloaded file is always named "report.csv".

In my controller:

```
def report
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv do
      render :template => "summary/report.csv.erb",
             :filename => "foo" #doesn't work
    end
  end
end
```

I think it's using the default renderer (I haven't implemented an alternate renderer), but I can't seem to find complete docs on the options available.

Isn't there something like a "filename" option or something that I can use?  Is there a better approach?

Comment: Maybe this post will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617055/setting-the-filename-for-a-downloaded-file-in-a-rails-application

Comment: I had seen that post before, but I looked at it again due to your comment, and it clicked.  I now have a working answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I got it, thanks to some help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3876038/650475).

```
format.csv do
  response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="' + filename + '.csv"'
  render "summary/report.csv.erb"
end
```

First you set the filename in the response header, then you call `render`.

(The template param to `render` is optional, but in my case I needed it.)

Comment: When trying this solution, I get: undefined local variable or method `headers'.  Any idea why this might happen?  Where is that response objcet coming from?

Comment: alright...  I got this to work by just doing headers, instead of response.headers

Comment: @deakolt - I can't entirely explain where that `response` variable comes from.  I think it's provided by [ActionController::Base](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html).  Maybe it's set by the `respond_to` block?  Without seeing your code, I can't guess what's different.

Comment: On Rails 3.2 I had to set the header _after_ calling render. This advice may need updated.

Comment: On Rails 4 must be also after the render as yock said.

Comment: Does anyone know why changing the header *after* calling `render` would work?  Isn't that like loading the boat after it's already left the dock?

Comment: I got this to work with an embedded PDF by changing the header to use "inline" instead of "attachment"

Answer (score 7):

You can pass the filename to `send_data` and let it handle the Content-Disposition header.

```
# config/initializers/csv_support.rb
ActionController::Renderers.add :csv do |csv, options|
  options = options.reverse_merge type: Mime::CSV
  content = csv.respond_to? :to_csv ? csv.to_csv : csv.to_s
  send_data content, options
end

# app/controllers/reports_controller.rb
respond_to do |format|
  format.html ...
  format.csv { render csv: my_report, filename: 'my_report.csv' }
end
```

Then add a `to_csv` method to `my_report` or pass a pre-generated CSV string.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you can use a combination of send_data and render_to_string (since you have a CSV template).

```
def report
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv do
      send_data render_to_string(:template => "summary/report.csv.erb"),
             :filename => "foo"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: according to documentation ":filename - suggests a filename for the browser to use." but it does not work. In Chrome, downloading the file it sets the name to the end of the route, 'path/download.csv'