# Rails 3 CSV and XLS export doesn't give file extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, xls

My users can generate a report of some data, and decide what format they want.

They can choose HTML,CSV or XLS

This is the form (Omitted the data stuff, this is just the format selector)

```
<%= form_tag "/report", :method => :get %>
    Format <select id='format' name='format'>
                <option value='html' selected='selected'>View in browser (HTML)</option>
                <option value='csv'>Export to CSV file</option>
                <option value='xls'>Export to exel (XLS)</option>
            </select>

<%= submit_tag "Make report", :class => 'submit' %>
```

This form goes to this action

```
def report
    #...Again omitting data stuff
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv 
      format.xls 
    end
  end
```

I have corresponding view files.

Like `report.xls.erb`

In my log I get

```
Processing by ..Controller#report as XLS
```

But, **the browser downloads the file without extension**.

If I change the form_tag line to this.

```
<%= form_tag "/report.xls", :method => :get %>
```

The file gets the .xls extension.

I have set the xls mime_types

How can I set the format in the form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is from different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617055/setting-the-filename-for-a-downloaded-file-in-a-rails-application).

You can set header to tell browser name of the file.

```rb
format.xls do
  response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="' + filename + '.xls"'
  render "report.xls.erb"
end
```