# Serving same PDF through multiple URLs without duplicating it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a pdf called `dummy.pdf` that I want to serve whenever someone visits different path names like `acme.pdf` or `apple.pdf`.

Since the path names are known in advance, is there a way to serve the PDF via different names (with a rails route perhaps) without duplicating the original pdf?

Answer (score 0):

I simple way to solve this problem is to change the filename downloaded only.
Take look at the links below, the method `send_data` could help you.

[setting the filename for a downloaded file in a rails application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617055/setting-the-filename-for-a-downloaded-file-in-a-rails-application)

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_data